# How to: snippet expansion in eclim?

Tags: code-snippets, expansion, eclim

I'm going direct to the question:
I want to be able to do the "sysout" snippet expansion like in eclipse
how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

```
EclimHelpGrep snippet
```

will give you

```
1.5.2 (Aug. 30, 2009)
=====================

Bug Fixes:
   - Various bug fixes.
Eclim:
   - Added |:ProjectRename| and |:ProjectMove| commands to allow
     renaming and moving of projects.
   - Added |:ProjectProblems| command to populate vim's quickfix
     with a list of all eclipse build errors and warnings for the
     current and all related projects.
     Note: To have problems reported for java projects created via
       eclim, you may need to recreate your java projects to ensure
       that the java builder is properly added.  As of eclim 1.5.2,
       eclim's java project creation now adds the java builder.

   - Added |:HistoryDiffNext| and |:HistoryDiffPrev| commands to
     view history diffs while navigating the history stack.
   - Abbreviation support removed in favor of any one of the third
     party snippets plugins available on vim.org (snipMate,
     snippetsEmu, etc.).
   - Added support for hosting third party nailgun apps in eclim via
     an ext dir (eclimd#eclimd-extdir).
Java:
   - Updated |:JavaImpl|, |:JavaDelegate|, and |:JUnitImpl| to
     better support generics.
   - Updated |:JUnitImpl| to support junit 4 method signatures.
   - Updated |:JavaImport| and :JavaImportSort to honor eclipse's
     import order preference and added the ability to edit that
     preference via |:ProjectSettings| and :EclimSettings.
   - Added initial refactoring (|vim-java-refactor|) support.
Git Log (1.5.2)
(https://github.com/ervandew/eclim/compare/1.5.1...1.5.2)
```

The relevant part is:

```
   - Abbreviation support removed in favor of any one of the third
     party snippets plugins available on vim.org (snipMate,
     snippetsEmu, etc.).
```

I'll look into those and update this. As of now I don't use any snippet plugin.